# Screen Sharing not working for non-admin local accounts on Yosemite Server

Tags: macos, osx-server, server.app, screen-sharing

Question says it all. Current versions of Yosemite (10.10.3) and Server (4.1).

Under Server > Settings
     Enable screen sharing and remote management checked.

Under Server > Access
     Admin and a non-admin local user listed.

I can log in Screen Sharing as the Admin user but not via non-admin accounts.

Comment: Did you add the non-admin user (or non-admin group) to the Remote Management pane itself in SysPrefs?

Comment: Bingo, that was the ticket. I had been ignoring it due to the "Screen Sharing is currently being controlled by the Remote Management service." message. Seems counterintuitive.

Convert your comment to an answer and I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to add the non-admin user/group (depending on if multiple users) to the Remote Management section of Sharing in System Preferences to allow access.

(Thanks Guy!)

Comment: While it seems counterintuitive given that you can grant access to services via the Server App the big warning in the System Preferences pane actually is telling you what needs to be done. If anyone has any insight as to the logic of why Apple made this functionality a two step process I'd like to know. Thank you in advance and thank you smoosher for the quick answer - I had been banging my head against it since setting up a Mac Mini with Server.